Trying to create 3D mesh structure with a particle inside it - Gmsh
Trying to create a 3D solid mesh structure which has a solid particle inside it. I want the box and the sphere both have non-overlapped mesh structure. But the BOX's mesh is also going inside the sphere's mesh. Trying to delete the volume of sphere from the box, and then generating 3D mesh for both. But its not working? Any suggestions?
SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");
Box(1) = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
Sphere(2) = {.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, -Pi, Pi, 2*Pi};
BooleanDifference(3) = { Volume{1}; Delete; }{ Volume{2}; Delete; };
Volume(5) = {3};
Physical Volume("Particle") = {5};
Physical Volume("Matrix") = {2};
I tried with Gmsh GUI with different Boolean operations. Not working as expected.

SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");
Box(1) = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
Sphere(2) = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2};
BooleanDifference { Volume{1}; Delete; }{ Volume{2};}
Physical Volume("Matrix",9) = {1};
Physical Volume("Particle",10) = {2};


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
